# Accessing a subdirectory in a form

Tags: php, forms, authentication, phpbb, subdirectory

I'm having a PHP problem that seems pretty easy to solve, but yet is giving me quite the search headache to find a solution for.

I'm running PHPBB and am creating an external login port to access certain fields in the SQL database. The problem in the code is coming because both PHPBB and the location I am logging in from exist on two separate subdirectories on the website.

Here is my PHP code:

```
   define("IN_PHPBB", true);
   define("PHPBB_ROOT_PATH", "../forums/");

   $phpbb_root_path = "../forums/";

   $phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, "."), 1);
   include($phpbb_root_path . "common." . $phpEx);
   include($phpbb_root_path . "includes/functions_display." . $phpEx);

   // Start session management
   $user->session_begin();
   $auth->acl($user->data);

   if ($user->data["is_registered"]) {
      echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"".$phpbb_root_path."ucp.php?mode=logout&amp;sid=".$user->data["session_id"]."\">";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"logout\" value=\"Logout\">";
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"redirect\" value=\"../index.php\">";
      echo "<br /></form>";
   }
   if (!$user->data["is_registered"]) {
      echo "Welcome! Please log-in to your forums account to proceed:<p>";
      echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"".$phpbb_root_path."ucp.php?mode=login\">";
      echo " Username:";
      echo "<br />";
      echo " <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"15\" value=\"\">";
      echo "<br /><br />";
      echo " Password:";
      echo "<br />";
      echo " <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" size=\"15\" value=\"\">";
      echo "<br /><br />";
      echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"login\" value=\"Login\">";
      echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"redirect\" value=\"../".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."\">";
      echo "<br /></form>";
   }
```

This code generates a 404 error on the website trying to access ucp.php on the subdirectory from which this php file is located, not the one on the forums. I tried using the full URL of the website in the form which allowed the script to function, but the forum session was not properly loaded and therefore just brought me back to the login page here with a session ID in the url.

Comment: This should be a routine debugging exercise: 404 = file not found. So, is the file in the place you expect it to be? Is your code actually looking there? Pay attention to `$phpbb_root_path` which traverses the directory tree up and down, and could well put you in the wrong place.

Comment: Wow, I really need to sit back and drink some more coffee. I guess sitting back and going through the code step by step would help me next time. Thanks for the help!